# glReadPixels() in OpenGL ES?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

If I write:

```
glColor4f(1.0,0,0, 1.0);
glReadPixels(touch1Point.x,viewport[3]-touch1Point.y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixelColor[0]);
```

...pixelColor is populated with RGB(255, 0, 0)

What is the right `glReadPixels()` call that will give me back RGB(1.0, 0, 0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide each component of `pixelColor` by `255.0f`